# Commerce discount rule

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

Have this scenario, a user must get 10% discount on only these products (product 1 & 2 is defined in rules), if at least 5 items of each is in cart.

Cart:

- 5 pcs    product 1         500
- 5 pcs    product 2          50
- 1 pcs    product 3         100

with the discount, the total will be 595, since the user will get 10% on 500+50 and not product 3

If the scenario is

- 5 pcs    product 1         500
- 4 pcs    product 2          50
- 1 pcs    product 3         100

the user will not get any discount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help if you add the rule that you have added. Also if you think it's a complex rule to be applied, you can apply the discount in the checkout page rather than before that without using the rules itself. In other places just display the 1pcs price with the discount applied.

Answer (score -1):

I sort of have figured half of it out.

the below isnt any particular programming language, but to show what i mean.

```
foreach (items as item)
  if (item.sku == v1 & item.value >= 5) or (item.sku == v2 & item.value >= 5) 
    item.price -= 10%
  endif
endforeach
```

My problem with rules is that both have to be present in the order.